# Excel COUNTIF returns ambiguous results

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to use Excel's COUNTIF formula on a large range of values to basically create a unique and sorted list of those values. However, several values don't seem to be considered in this operation, so I went to debugging it.

Could you explain to me why the values in column B of the snipet table below are all '0'? What is the catch to obtain a value of '1' when comparing values like the ones below?

I understand I'm probably missing some silly detail...

Thanks in advance

```
   -----------------
   |   A   |   B   |
   -----------------
1  | 10 B  |   0   |  <-- B1 formula is =COUNTIF(A1;"<52")
   -----------------
2  |  52   |   0   |  <-- B2 formula is =COUNTIF(A2;"<10 B")
   -----------------
3  |  52   |   0   |  <-- B3 formula is =COUNTIF(A3;"=10 B")
   -----------------
```

**EDIT:**
Let me put this into perspective. Consider the table below.

What I'm trying to achieve exactly is, on column B, construct a list of unique values from column A. I'm doing this by using the following formula on B2, with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and dragging it through cells in B column, B3, B4, etc:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$100;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($A$2:$A$100;"<"&$A$2:$A$100)-SUM(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$100;B$1:B1));0))
```

However, several values from column A are "skipped", hence why I've tried debuging the COUNTIF formula like I explained above, but still no idea why certain values are skipped, perhaps an error with the formula?

```
    -----------------------
    |     A    |     B    |
    -----------------------
 1  |          |          |
    -----------------------
 2  |    52    |    52    |
    -----------------------
 3  |   16277  |  16277   |
    -----------------------
 4  |   16277  |  21785   |
    -----------------------
 5  |   16277  | 5411828  |
    -----------------------
 6  |   21785  | 54112528 |
    -----------------------
 7  |  5411828 |   37-50  |
    -----------------------
 8  | 54112528 |   42-B   |
    -----------------------
 9  |   10 B   |  ABC-01  |
    -----------------------
10  |   10-M   |          |
    -----------------------
11  |   15-94  |          |
    -----------------------
12  |  15-971/ |          |
    -----------------------
13  |   16.    |          |
    -----------------------
14  |   16..   |          |
    -----------------------
15  |   22-23  |          |
    -----------------------
16  |   37-50  |          |
    -----------------------
17  |   42-B   |          |
    -----------------------
18  |  ABC-01  |          |
    -----------------------
```

Comment: "10 B" is not a number hence the zero

Comment: Even if you get past all the problems with comparing true numbers against text-that-look-like-numbers, none of those countif formulas would return anything but zero.

Answer (score 2):

For the first row, "10 B" is not a numerical value, so it cannot fit the `COUNTIF` criteria of being less than 52. If that field will always have a number and letter then you could parse out the number with `LEFT(A1,2)` to get the two digits on the left, and then see if they're less than 52.

For the second and third rows your `COUNTIF` is looking for criteria that is less than a non-numerical value, so the function won't work. You could `COUNTIF` if the cell value was equal to that criteria, looking for a match. Or you could change the formula to `COUNTIF(A3,"<10")` which would then return a count of any cells that are less than 10.

Your primary issue seems to be differentiating between numbers, and numbers with letters. In excel, when you have a cell with letters and/or spaces in addition to numbers, it will typically format to a text field and so mathematical formulas will not use it with out some tweaking.

Comment: Just to clarify - "10 B" **is** a value, it just isn't a number and `LEFT(A1,2)` is still going to return text (e.g. "10") that looks like a number but isn't one. Use `=--LEFT(A1,2)`, `=0+LEFT(A1,2)`, `=LEFT(A1,2)*1` or `=VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))` to retrieve a true number.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm trying to use Excel's COUNTIF formula on a large range of values to basically create a unique and sorted list of those values.*

What you have just described there can be accomplished easily with a PivotTable, with the field of interest in both the Rows area and in the Values area as a Count.

Comment: yes, your idea seems familiar to me, it looks like it might help out achieve what I need, could you point out some good sources to read to construct one? also I've edited my initial question to bring the original issue more into perspective

Comment: Plenty of tutorials on Google (including on the Excel Campus site, the Chandoo blog, and the Contextures website) and YouTube (including the ExcelIsFun channel that has thousands of videos)